# Loading shared model in ui-router states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

Is there any better way to load a`shared model` before the `state` change?

```
....
....
.state('state1',{
      ...
      resolve : {
           student : function($stateParams,StudentModel,StudentService){
                  return StudentService.getStudentById($stateParams.studentId).then(
                       function(response){
                            return StudentModel.loadStudent(response.data);
                       }
                  );
           }
      }
}).....
.....
...
```

In my current application, I use `resolve` attribute to load all my `shared data models` so that no `controllers/directives` will be executed before the  `StudentModel` is populated. But here, For the sake of loading `StudentModel`, I'm creating a `resolved object (student in this case)` in the `state` which I'm not going to use anywhere else.

Is there any better way to load my `shared models` before other `controllers/directives` are loaded for a particular `state`?

*[Note : I am using angular 1.4.2 version ]*

**Update: Sorry that I missed return statement in the code above which has created some confusion. My question is not about to make the above code work.  Is there any alternative way for the same behaviour ? because in this design, I have to create a resolve object (`student`) which is not going to be used anywhere and `StudentModel` is the one which is used everywhere.**

Answer (score 1):

As such you haven't implemented promise function correctly. It should return promise to wait view to render.

**Code**

```
student: function($stateParams, StudentModel, StudentService) {
  return StudentService.getStudentById($stateParams.studentId).then(
    function(response) {
      return StudentModel.loadStudent(response.data);
    }
  );
}
```

Other than this, can you please elaborate on below line from question?

> *Is there any better way to load my shared models before other    controllers/directives are loaded for a particular state?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a $promise in the resolve so that the data can be loaded before the controller is created.

```
  resolve : {
       student : function($stateParams,StudentModel,StudentService){
              StudentService.getStudentById($stateParams.studentId).$promise;                  
       }
  }
```

Then in your controller you need to get the students from the parameter.

```
var StudentController = function(student, $scope) {
     ....
}
app.controller("StudentController", ["student", "$scope", StudentController]);
```